Who was the youngest archbishop ever?
Here is a link to a question asking about the youngest bishop ever.
Has there ever been an archbishop or bishop younger than the 16-year-old James of Nicosia?
There are many answers to the question, including one of mine.
Archbishops are a category of bishops, higher ranked bishops.  Some but not all bishops are archbishops, but all archbishops are bishops.  So the youngest bishop should be either the youngest archbishop or else younger than the youngest archbishop.
And now I ask the obvious related question about archbishops, since the youngest archbishop might be years older than the youngest bishop.
Who was the youngest archbishop ever?

And here is the first answer to my question, the age at becoming archbishop that other answers will have to beat.
Alexander Stewart, an illegitimate son of King James IV of Scotland,was born about 1493 and was made Archbishop of Saint Andrews aged 11 on 10 may 1504.  He was killed along with his father fighting at the Battle of Flodden in 1513 aged about 20.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Stewart_(archbishop_of_St_Andrews)
https://fmg.ac/Projects/MedLands/SCOTLAND.htm#JamesIVdied1513
https://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/bishop/bstewaral.html
Thus he may count as the youngest Archbishop ever.

Why Hugh of Vermandois, Archbishop of Reims (o. 925, 5 years) and Luis Antonio Jaime of Spain, Archbishop of Toledo (o. 1735, 8 years), answers to the question you linked, didn't work for you? I understand the first one lacks online sources, but Luis Antonio don't.

@CarlosMartin actually there are online sources for Hugh too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugh_of_Vermandois_(bishop) (with more links from the French page : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugues_de_Reims )

@Evargalo Thank you for the links. It's settled then, that answer did an amazing work to track the youngest bishops so I don't think there was an archbishop younger than 5.
